# Is the sealed command c++ 0x or is it only microsoft who has it

Tags: c++11, c++-cli, sealed

Is the `sealed` command going to be in c++ 0x or is it only MS who use it?

Comment: What is "the sealed command"? Where are you taking that from? C++0x introduces "final" and "override", maybe that's what you're after?

Comment: Its actually from a different language "C++/CLI". Though it is based on C++ it is not the same language.

Comment: In any case, it is not specific to C++0x.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C++0x has a special identifier `final` which means the same as `sealed` for classes in C++/CLI. It prevents a class from being derived from.

[Read about sealed in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicit_overrides_and_final)

So the answer is basically: it already is but under a different name and has a different syntax.

Answer (score 3):

`sealed` is a really .net term and so is specific to MS C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Sealed is used to declare a .net class that cannot be derived from. It's available in C++ but on for .net types in MC++.