# Prevent inheritor class from overriding virtual function of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++-cli, virtual

The situation is like this.

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class MyClass : Interface
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
private:
    void foo()
    {
        //Some private work and checks.
        bar();
    };
}
```

I want that my user will create a class which inherit from MyClass, and they will have to implement there `bar()`.
But how can I enfoce they wouldn't override `foo()`? because it's important to me to use my `foo()`.

Comment: Does this compile? If so, you don't have a problem, since your foo is private. Edit: ah, no, it doesn't compile...

Comment: @MrLister: Private methods can still be overriden.

Comment: True, sorry. Never mind then. The answer already has been given.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++11 you can mark the method as `final` to prevent it from being overriden:

```
class MyClass : Interface
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
private:
    void foo() final
    {
        //Some private work and checks.
        bar();
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you lead me to the right direction. but in C++11V1.0 `final` was changed into `sealed`.

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026462). `sealed` is microsoft-specific. `final` is defined in §7.6.4 [dcl.attr.final] of the C++11-standard.

Answer (score 6):

As per other answer, you can use `final` keyword in C++11 (such facility is similar to Java's `final` keyword).

For C++03 code, you can use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) mechanism (provided if you can change the definition of `Interface`)

```
template<typename Derived>
class Interface
{
public:
  void foo()  // not 'virtual'
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();
  }
}

class MyClass : public Interface<MyClass>
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
private:
    void foo()
    {
        //Some private work and checks.
        bar();
    };
}
```

So now you have remove the `virtual`ness of the `foo()` and the binding will happen at compile time. Remember that CRTP comes with its own limitation, so whether to use it or not is up to you.